# VB: Declaring variables in For loop

Tags: vb6, for-loop

I have been trying to declare variables inside a For loop for quite some time now, and I just haven't been able to find a way.
I'm attempting to create a new image (tile) for every time a certain number is encountered in a two-dimensioned array (Measuring 32x16). I may need to add in that I am using Visual Basic 6.

Currently I'm using the following code:

```
Option Explicit
Dim wCount As Integer
Dim hCount As Integer
Dim arrTiles(31, 15) As Integer


Private Sub Form_Load()
    For wCount = 0 To 31 Step 1
        For hCount = 0 To 15 Step 1
            ' -Declare variables
            ' -I.E. Dim NAME As Image
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

However, the above code (Using Dim tile1 As Image) gives me an error whenever trying to access one of the properties of the newly added image (Such as tile1.Width).

Is there any way to declare a variable this way at run-time?

Sincerely
- Birjolaxew

Comment: Is the error a NullReferenceException?

Comment: @matt: No, an "Object variable or With block variable not set".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must assign a valid Image object to the Image variable before you try to access any properties of it. For example, this works fine:

```
    For wCount = 0 To 31 Step 1
        For hCount = 0 To 15 Step 1
            ' -Declare variables
            Dim tile1 As Image
            tile1 = Image.FromFile("c:/test.png")
            Dim width = tile1.Width
        Next
    Next
```

Comment: Thank you! I am, however, unfortunately afraid that I need a bit more help. If I attempted to use Image.FromFile("PATH"), it stated that no such function could be found. I tried googling, and found "LoadPicture", but I can't seem to get that to work either. Do you, by any chance, have an idea as of for what the function could be?

Comment: I'm not using VB6, Sorry. It looks like tile1.Picture = LoadPicture("PATH") will do what my example above does. If that's not working, I wouldn't know why. Maybe if you posted some more of your code in the original post, someone with more VB6 knowledge might see your problem. I wish I could be more help.

Comment: Thank you for the help anyway. I will look into it myself. In the mean-time, I marked yours as the answer, as it obviously helped me far along the road to the answer.